# Can I safely substitute a readonly property for a readonly public field?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

My team follows the general .NET convention that you should expose public properties on your types rather than exposing fields. However, I've come across a class which *mostly* exposes fields... but then contains this for its two 'identifying' pieces of data:

```cs
public readonly int WidgetId;
public readonly string WidgetName;
```

I am really heavily tempted to refactor these into properties, i.e.

```cs
public int WidgetId { get; }
public string WidgetName { get; }
```

So they match the conventions of the rest of the class. I'm aware of the arguments for and against public fields versus properties. But, given that *readonly-auto-properties* in particular are a relatively new C# feature, I want to know:

What are the semantic differences between `public readonly int Foo` and `public int Foo { get; }`, if any? Are they meaningfully different to the compiler?

Comment: @PeterDuniho it does not seem to me a duplicate. The question is about readonly properties and fields, not about readonly and private keywords.

Comment: @Backs: _"not about readonly and private keywords"_ -- of course it is. `readonly` applies _only_ to fields. A "read-only" property is simply one without an accessible setter. Whether the inaccessibility is because the setter simply isn't present or because it's `private` is completely irrelevant. This is still in its essence a question identical to all the others that have been asked over the years.

Comment: I'm fine with this being marked duplicate if it funnels to information that materially answers the question. Unfortunately, since the **readonly-auto-property** feature in C# is relatively new, a lot of what's in the linked threads doesn't really apply. The thing I found that *strictly* answers the question "how do a public readonly field and a public readonly property differ in semantics?" is [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-c-6/), which demonstrates the IL for a public readonly property: looks like there's no semantic difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your new property is equal to:

```
private readonly string _widgetName = GetWidgetName();
public string WidgetName
{
    get { return _widgetName; }
}
```

So, the value is stored in `_widgetName` and it's safe because it's readonly, and you can't change it's value as before.

With property `WidgetName` you can only change access to field `_widgetName`, not the value. For example:

```
private readonly string _widgetName = GetWidgetName();
public string WidgetName
{
    get 
    {
        if (_widgetName == null) throw new Exception("Value is not set"); 
        return _widgetName; 
    }
}
```

You get more control to your data, but in common case - there is no difference, if you just replcae `readonly` field to `readonly` propery.

Some information about properties is [here](http://blog.rogatnev.net/2017/09/13/Varieties-of-properties.html).